# How to replay the traffic recorded by Wireshark using scapy in Windows 10?

Tags: python, wireshark

1. I played some traffic from PC a (192.168.0.212) to PC b (192.168.0.234), both are windows 10.
2. When I played the traffic, the Wireshark is opened, and there is what I saw:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfVMR.png)
3. I used scapy which that code is generated by chatGPT, and as following:

```
from scapy.all import \*

def replay_packets(pcap_file):
    packets = rdpcap(pcap_file)
    iface = "eth0"
    print(f"We totally captured {len(packets)} packets.")
    for packet in packets:
        try:
            sendp(packet, iface=iface, verbose=False)
            print("We have replayed one packet.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error happened when sending packet...: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
pcap_file = "test.pcapng"
replay_packets(pcap_file)
```

4. When I replay the traffic, I opened the Wireshark to motinor the traffic, and it seems to be some problems... all the length of TCP packet is 0??
   [image]
5. What should I do to correctly replay the traffic?

As above mentioned.